# Yii2 RestApi Standards Routing

Tags: yii2

Всех приветствую. Реализую RestApi, используя Yii2. Создал контроллеры для рест в отдельной папке. Структура такая: 
-app/
    controllers/
               /rest/
Соответственно в папке rest лежат нужные мне контролеры, реализующие методы, необходимые мне. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы к actions можно было обращаться в соответствии с http-методами, т.е. по стандартам RestApi. Судя по документации, для этого нужно настроить url-manager. 
Url-manager имеет вид:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => [                
            '\app\controllers\rest\CheckListController',
            '\app\controllers\rest\ItemController',
            '\app\controllers\rest\AuthController'   
        ]
    ],
]
```

Но суть в том, что после такой настройки все мои actions стали недостижимы. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, как настроить нормальный routing и поддержку http-методов.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге удалось сделать так, чтобы методы работали по стандартам RestApi. Для этого понадобилось изменить конфиги так:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'rest/check-list',
                        'rest/item',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: те контролеры в которых методы не соответствуют http-методам становятся недостижимы. Поэтому, если кто-то знает как настроить это, буду очень благодарен.